# R data.table melt converts NAs into (close to zero) values

Tags: r

I create an excel spreadsheet with some blanks (I never enter anything into those cells)  in the second, third, etc. columns. The first column is the ID variable for the observation and is never missing. Furthermore, in the second through last columns, there all values are numeric and large positive numbers, certainly nothing close to zero. I save as `.csv`. I import to an R data.table using `fread`.

The blank cells are reflected as `NA` in `R`, and return `TRUE` when queried by `is.na()`. However, when displaying the cells in the RStudio viewer, some of the `NA`s are on the left side of the cell and some are on the right side of the cell. Further, when I display those values in the console, it returns `<NA>`, while the others (rendered on the left) return `NA`.

My data.table is called, say, `data`. I melt `data` to convert to long form, to collapse all of the columns beside the first one into two columns, i.e., I do

```
data <- melt(data, id.vars = 1, measure.vars = 2:length(names(data)))
```

When I then inspect the result, there are many entries in the `value` column equal to a numeric value very close to zero. It turns out that these correspond exactly to those in the original data.table with the `NA` value rendered on the right of the cell, as opposed to the left. I emphasize at this point that those very cells returned `TRUE` when queried by `is.na()` in the initial data.

This seems to have something to do with the difference between `<NA>` and `NA`, but I still don't see why under any circumstance `melt` should turn any `NA` or `<NA>` value into a non-missing value.

Comment: First your melt is wrong. There is no change to your data shape. Probably you interchanged the id.var and the measure.vars

Comment: yes, I did, that's a typo in the question, which I have now fixed. I don't agree with your vote to close my question on account of what is clearly a typo (as you suggest in your comment).

Comment: I ended up fixing the problem by changing the format of the cells in excel before saving as csv. It had to do with scientific notation and them being imported as Int64 in R, possibly. But the question remains why it would convert them to non-NA values upon melting, so I leave the question up.